# c# /// summary, SINGLE line break (IntelliSense)

Tags: c#, newline, break, summary

If I use the `<para></para>` statement in a C# `///summary`, I get a blank line and then the text goes on, which is equivalent to two line breaks (`<br/>` or \n).

However I'd really like to add single line breaks, which just cause my text to start at the next line, without leaving a blank line in between.

The suggested solutions don't work for me, see a screenshot:
[Two line breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtUfm.png)

**Update: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Visual Assist Plugin, no manual changes done to any intelli-sense formatting options.**

**Update 2: It's not caused by the Visual Assist Plugin (I disabled it). It seems to be simply different in VS2015.**

Comment: Is this question just on (auto) formatting XML Documetation Comments in your source, or adapt the output of the IntelliSense tooltip?

Comment: In intellisense there is no empty line between.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hence I am asking ...

Comment: @TimSchmelter :) my bad ... sry

Comment: IntelliSense, I just added a screenshot.

Comment: @jmd42: [here's my screenshot](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151009/l78cxg9t.png) (VS 2010, no Visual Assist Plugin):

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Very interesting... I just disabled Visual Assist, and i still have double line breaks. Maybe it's just different on VS2015.

Comment: [Just a regular `<br />` works fine on my install of Visual Studio 2015. (Click for screenshot)](http://i.imgur.com/LVRDRCr.png)

Comment: @JoshuaShearer: Sadly it won't work for me, <br /> or <br/> just disappears and <br> breaks the whole summary element, so that it is not shown anymore. Do I have to enable HTML support or something similar?

Comment: @jmd42 I suppose it may work due to an extension on my installation.  Perhaps ReSharper and/or GhostDoc alter the default functionality of my tooltips?  I'd verify this, but all my machines have both these extensions installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra blank line displayed from <para></para> and <para /> in VS2015CE, can't get rid of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598859/extra-blank-line-displayed-from-para-para-and-para-in-vs2015ce-cant-ge)

Answer (score 1):

This is by the design of visual studio editor. If you are using Visual Studio's editor to view the summary, they have restricted it for limited html elements. You can still use most of the html elements to format your summary and will be applied when you export the documentation, but visual studio ignores them.

I think resharper intellisense formats the summary with