# VS 2017 Function Comments - Create new line NOT paragraph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have found many QA on SO that talk about how to create a new `PARAGRAPH` (aka a blank line between two lines).  However, I'm trying to create a `NEW LINE` (just a return to a new line).  Is this possible?  Sorry if this is a duplicate, everything I could find did not address this EXACT question that I could find.

**What I'm currently using in my source...**

```
/// <summary>
/// Some header text.
/// <para>This is the first paragraph created.</para>
/// <para>This is the second paragraph created.</para>
/// Some footer text.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>bool value</returns>
public bool TestFunction(string par)
{
    return true;
}
```

**This ends up with the following results...**

[image]

**What I'm looking for in the results is the following...**

[image]

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598859/extra-blank-line-displayed-from-para-para-and-para-in-vs2015ce-cant-ge

Comment: Sure enough @GonzaloLorieto...  I figured someone had to have asked it before I just could not find it.  And of coarse the answer that was provided was not what I was looking for..  :/

Comment: But, that question was answered back in 2016...  Possibly something has changed since then?

Comment: Microsoft docs about this hasn't been updated since 07/19/2015

Comment: There is some irony there somewhere...